How to delete files with specific extension older than 3 days with ForFiles?
I need to delete files with 001 extension older than 3 days, forfiles gives me error and I have tried for hours to fix that, but I don't know whats wrong. I really need some help.
My command is ForFiles /p "C:\Db2_Backup\" /M *.001 /s /d -3 /c "cmd /c del /q /s @file"
It gives me ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '/q'
I have tried to use different mask, like whats in the file name or put it in quotes, but no luck. If I delete /q parameter it gives me ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@file' error...
Thank you.

file only lists the file name and the file may be on a specific path since you used the include subfolders /s option. So you should use path instead of file to delete the file del /q @path

@RicardoBohner Tried that, no luck. Same results.

Aparantly, you cant use " " for the pathname. By changing the full command to ForFiles /p C:\Db2_Backup\ /M *.001 /s /d -3 /c "cmd /c del /q /s @file" it executed correctly for me.

Wow, didn't expect that... Especially since it worked fine in other line, where I did not use mask. Thank you.

Interesting, what if the /p path has spaces in it?

You'll have to use old style short 8.3 names like "c:\path too long" becomes c:\pathto∼1 . Its an old tool and i wouldnt advise to continue to make use of it. But since the solution was so easy in this case, may as well.
